# Проблема в инициализации branch.io

Tags: java, android

Использую библиотеку branch.io для работы с app link.
В манифесте указываю intent-filter для Branch URI scheme:

```
<intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="***" android:host="open" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
```

Для App Links в манифесте указано:

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="***.app.link" />
            <data
                android:host="***-alternate.app.link"
                android:scheme="https"/>
            <data
                android:host="***.test-app.link"
                android:scheme="https"/>
            <data
                android:host="***-alternate.test-app.link"
                android:scheme="https"/>
```

LaunchMode у AppLinkActivity указан как singleTask.
Инициализирую Branch в Application классе, в методе onCreate:

```
Branch.getAutoInstance(this);
```

При открытии AppLinkActivity я получаю instance и инициализирую сессию:

```
   Branch branch = Branch.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
   branch.initSession((referringParams, error) -> {
        LogFileUtil.writeLog("Finish init session");
        if (error == null) {
            //Кое что делаю
        } else {
           //Кое что делаю
        }
    }, this.getIntent().getData(), this);
```

Теперь к проблеме. Когда я открываю приложение через AppLink параметр referringParams не пустой и я могу выдернуть из него необходимые мне данные. Но когда мое приложение открыто и я нажимаю по AppLink'y из другого приложения, то параметр referringParams становится пустым. Мне кажется, что дело в инициализации Branch. Как это можно поправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение - необходимо сделать класс AppLinkActivity главным. Т.е. у этого активити должен присутствовать еще один intent-filter:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
```